# Devise before_action :authenticate_admin! not authenticating admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I have used devise numerous times but currently facing an issue at the moment.

I used this devise wiki to set up devise with multiple user models which i have done multiple times. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models

In my admins_controller.rb i have the following code

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
end
```

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admins', controllers: {sessions: "admins/sessions", registrations: "admins/registrations"}

  namespace :admins do
    root "dashboards#index"
  end
end
```

Everything else works well but after i try to sign in as an admin, it should redirect to my admins root but i always get this error

```
You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
```

But when i do `admin_signed_in?` or `current_admin`. I get true and my admin record accordingly. Which means the admin is already signed in.

When i comment the `before_action` code, then it works perfectly.

Currently stuck and cannot think of why and how to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share whole `routes.rb` where you would have setup root for non admin users?

Comment: Hi @AmitPatel i ended up solving it apparently this line in config/environments/development.rb breaks in my application `config.session_store :cache_store`

Comment: What make it work?